# Create tabulation in answer text field?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

Is it possible to create an index key for a Paragraph answer field?

For example:

```
Google Form Question: Name of cities:

|----------------------------------|
|1.                                |
|2.                                |
|3.                                |
|----------------------------------|
```

So it automatically fills "1." then when I press enter, fills with "2." and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible exactly the way you described, but there are two things you can do:

> 1. **Create a form with pre-filled responses**

[image]

[image]

Programmatically you can achieve this functionality with the methods [withItemResponse()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#withitemresponseresponse) and [toPrefilledUrl()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form-response#toPrefilledUrl()):

```
function prefillParagraphResponse(){
  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm(); 
  var items = form.getItems();
  var paragraphItem;
  for(var i in items){
    if(items[i].getTitle()=="Google Form Question: Name of cities"){
      paragraphItem=items[i];
      }
   }   
  Logger.log(form.createResponse().withItemResponse(paragraphItem.asParagraphTextItem().createResponse("1. \n2. \n3.")).toPrefilledUrl());
}
```

> 2. **Split the question in several questions**

[image]

This has the advantage of all answers being stored as a separate entry of the array [itemResponses](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response#), and you can programmatically assign a different index key to each one and access them selectively - if this is your purpose.